# Symfony - How to set attributes of two-part rendered DateTimeType Field?

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, twig

I want to set attribute of a two-part rendered DateTimeType Field. I render a two-part DateTimeType field with setting `date_widget` and `time_widget` to `'single_text'`:

```
$builder
    ->add('startDate', DateTimeType::class, array(
        'date_widget'   => 'single_text',
        'time_widget'   => 'single_text',
        'date_format'   => \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
        'with_seconds'  => false,
        'input'         => 'datetime',
        'label'         => 'bundle_name.form.travel.startDate',
        'attr'          => array('class' => 'peter')
    ))
```

Here the attribute (`attr`) `class="peter"` gets not applied to the two input fields but to the wrapped around `div`:

```
<div id="travel_startDate" class="peter">
    <div class="bootstrap-datepicker date">
        <input type="text" id="travel_startDate_date" name="travel[startDate][date]" required="required" class="form-control" value="2/1/17" />
    </div>
    <input type="time"  id="travel_startDate_time" name="travel[startDate][time]" required="required" class="form-control" value="22:02" />
</div>
```

How can I set attributes for the `input` fields INSIDE the `add(...)` function of the form builder?

I especially ask because I do not want to set the widgets in the `twig` template by hand.

Comment: Frankly I don't know if it's even possible. But, you can reach your purpose by using simple css trick. See https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/

Comment: @ihsan Setting the class attribute was just an example... but thanks. I looked up all options of the `DateTimeType` field and came to the conclusion that is not possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved by adjusting your form theme in Symfony. 
The following part in my theme did the trick for me:

```
{% block datetime_widget -%}
{% if widget == 'single_text' %}
    {{- block('form_widget_simple') -}}
{% else %}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({class: (attr.class|default('') ~ ' form-inline')|trim}) %}
    {% set widget_attr = {class: ''} %}
    {% if attr.class is defined and 'datepicker' in attr.class %}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({class: attr.class|replace({'datepicker' : ''}) }) %}
        {% set widget_attr = widget_attr|merge({class: 'datepicker' }) %}
    {% endif %}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        {{ form_errors(form.date) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.time) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.date, { datetime: true, attr: widget_attr } ) }}&nbsp;
        {{ form_widget(form.time, { datetime: true } ) }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
{%- endblock datetime_widget %}
```

In short:

- check if the datepicker class exists in the provided attr.class
- replace datepicker
- move it to the widget_attr
- pass widget_attr as attribute to the text widget

Comment: Now when thinking about it after quite a while I would come to the same solution. But its a little anoying. So much work just for a simple attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I use material kit and I wanted to add the "select picker" class to each html select tag of year month and day. I achieve that with the following way. I write the form by hand and pass the attr option to form_row.

{{.(form.date_start.day,{'attr':{'class':'selectpicker'}}) }}

...added from mobile, for the history